# Exception handling for controller actions which return view result with abp framework

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

I migrated my plain asp.net core project to Abp framework(open source). Im using both razor pages and mvc views together. So far there is no big issue. Abp not handles the exceptions for controller actions which returns view result [(related doc link)](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Exception-Handling#automatic-exception-handling) but i want to handle it too. How can I do that?

I have used Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer to log exceptions. But I dont want a new table for logging. I just want to use AbpAuditLogs for all the exceptions.

Edit1: To be clear I dont want to send exception details to the clients. But I want to log exception details to AbpAuditLogs table not to log file.

Edit2: I tracked down to [this](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/8619e23b9d90cbfd338bba784f095e969952af15/modules/audit-logging/src/Volo.Abp.AuditLogging.Domain/Volo/Abp/AuditLogging/AuditLogInfoToAuditLogConverter.cs#L58) line. Why audit logs using "SendExceptionsDetailsToClients" option? I think there should be a new option like "AddExceptionDetailsToAuditLogs".

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `AbpExceptionFilter`'s `ShouldHandleException` method to allow exception handling for view results as follows:

```cs
public class MyAbpExceptionFilter : AbpExceptionFilter
{
    protected override bool ShouldHandleException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //if the result is view result then handle the exception
        if (typeof(ViewResult).IsAssignableFrom(context.ActionDescriptor.GetReturnType()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        return base.ShouldHandleException(context);
    }
}
```

Then you can configure the `MvcOptions` to use your own exception filter:

```cs
        Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Remove(new ServiceFilterAttribute(typeof(AbpExceptionFilter)));
            options.Filters.AddService(typeof(MyAbpExceptionFilter));
        });
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing has changed. It still only logs :
```[    {      "code": null,      "message": "Sayfa işlenirken sunucu tarafında beklenmedik bir hata oluştu!",      "details": null,      "data": {},      "validationErrors": null    }  ]```
I want the exception details in the logs.

Comment: can you examine it in debug mode and ensure it's hit the breakpoint that you set on the MyAbpExceptionFilter class?

Comment: I have changed the above code a litle bit: 

```
protected override bool ShouldHandleException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            var type = context.ActionDescriptor.GetReturnType();
            if (typeof(Task<IActionResult>).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (typeof(IActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.ShouldHandleException(context);
        }
```

And yes it hits when i add breakpoint.